# I hit flood water at 60kph

Tags: car, head-gasket, water-pump, mechanics-trade, wont-stay-running

Hit flood water on a dark road at 60kph.
Car stalled midway, got towed, wouldn't start again. Lights still work and the car still cranks but doesn't start, air filter was dry, tried push starting it and it just made a rattling noise, almost started with jumper cables. Coolant level dropped very fast. Water coming out of exhaust when trying to start. Dried everything off, no water in oil. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the make, model, engine and fuel of the vehicle?

Comment: Are you saying that the air filter didn’t get wet during the incident?